# A function error preventing screen load in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I got two screens in my flutter app.
It's an app to simulate an online payment.
Anyway, I have this function on my second screen:

```
final salaire = TextEditingController();
final valeurAcq = TextEditingController();
final valeurApport = TextEditingController();
final moisRembours = TextEditingController();
final typeCreditChoisis = TextEditingController();

  double calcul(salaire, valeurAcq, valeurApport, moisRembours)
  {
  double res = (double.parse(salaire.text) -
  double.parse(valeurApport.text) / double.parse(moisRembours.text));
  return res;
  }
```

This function is triggered with `onPressed` in a button in second screen after filling a form.

```
child: MaterialButton(
minWidth: double.infinity,
height: 60,
onPressed: () {
calculCredit(salaire, valeurAcq,
valeurApport, moisRembours);
},
```

So , I launched my simulator and on my first screen when I click on a button that should bring the second page , I got an error in my function .

Assuming the problem is that Dart failed to parse the controller to `double` and causing an exception.

PS: The second screen won't open.[image: Error]

Error :

```
FormatException (FormatException: Invalid double)
```

Comment: and what value exactly you're entering?

Comment: So what value was present in `salaire.text` at the point you got the exception? Did you check `double.parse` documentation about what values are expected? What do you think should be the proper course of action when an invalid value is encountered? What options do you have to achieve it? Is it also possible for a user to supply invalid value that won't parse?

Comment: @OMiShah:  the entered value is String from a TextFieldForm. I'm trying to parse it to double .

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek :  at the moment of loading it's empty.

Comment: the input should not be null !!

Comment: @OMiShah: at the moment of the load of the screen it's null , the function is triggered when a button is clicked after filling the form.

Comment: @OMiShah : I tried adding.  initialValue: "0" in my inputs. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test With this :

```
double res = (double.parse(salaire.text ?? "0") -
      (double.parse(valeurApport.text??  "0") / double.parse(moisRembours.text ?? "0" ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding initial value to my inputs using my controllers fixed the problem.

```
final salaire = TextEditingController()..text = '0';
final valeurAcq = TextEditingController()..text = '0';
final valeurApport = TextEditingController()..text = '0';
final moisRembours = TextEditingController()..text = '0';
```